# Which definition of putExtra is used when a Messenger is packed into an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am starting a Service from an Activity by passing an Intent like this:

```
intent.putExtra("MESSENGER", new Messenger(handler));
```

The above line works correctly, but I would like to understand how it works since I have not converted the Messenger into a Parcel. Is this definition of putExtra being used?

```
putExtra(String name, Serializable value)
```

-Amit

Answer (score 1):

`Messenger` does not implement `Serializable`  but it implements `Parcelable` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html)):

```
public final class
Messenger
  extends Object
  implements Parcelable
```

so it is:

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, Parcelable value)
```

[docs here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable)).